# SQL Server CE, type or namespace not found on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, sql-server-ce

> The type or namespace name 'SqlServerCe' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Builds locally, won't build on Azure Devops

This *may* be intentional? The app is deployed on a local corporate network and not meant for public consumption.

Again, builds locally and all references are correct and working otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the SQL Compact runtime on the build server as part of your build, apparently it is not installed by default:

For SQL Compact 3.5, use:

```
msiexec /i %Build_SourcesDirectory%\tools\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi /quiet /qn

msiexec /i %Build_SourcesDirectory%\tools\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.msi /quiet /qn
```

For SQL Compact 4.0, use:

```
 %Build_SourcesDirectory%\tools\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe /quiet /qn
```

Comment: I feel like this is an incomplete answer. Not everyone knows what to do with that command line. I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in azure-pipelines.yml

```
steps:
- script: msiexec /i %Build_SourcesDirectory%\YourFolder\Driver\3.5.8109.0\SSCERuntime-ENU_x86.msi /quiet /qn 
  displayName: install SSCERuntime-ENU_x86.msi
- script: msiexec /i %Build_SourcesDirectory%\YourFolder\Driver\3.5.8109.0\SSCERuntime-ENU_x64.msi /quiet /qn
  displayName: install SSCERuntime-ENU_x64.msi
```